# Please check your wallet and daemon log for errors. You can also try to start monerod.exe manually

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, daemon, transaction-confirmation

I send this amount around 40 days earlier but still not credited to beneficiary address.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with this transaction.?

2nd questions. # This address received 940..502 monero, with 28524 confirmation(s)

Details:

Tx ID:

```
56e5b0b467e55e137059de0278e2798153123b378d8c628bb5be47fce374f531
```

Comment: Sorry what is the question?

Comment: @p2pexchange please see http://www.dictionary.com/browse/question